# How to resize the GPT partition table itself on Linux?

Tags: debian, gpt

I have cloned a 1GB pen drive to an 8GB one using `dd`.

But the size of the GPT is still 1GB. For example the secondary (backup) GPT is still located at 1GB (it has to be moved to the end of the disk).

Also I think [two fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_table_header_(LBA_1)) inside the main GPT (at offset 32 and 48) have to be updated.

I've looked into `gdisk` but couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table Has Google broken down again today? ;-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov My GPT is not corrupt. I want to resize an intact GPT. I googled for "resize GPT" but it only shows results about resizing partitions.

Comment: Your GPT is essentially corrupt (misplaced and misaligned). The answers on the page apply to your case.

Comment: Typically better to just create new gpt partitions on drive & rsync data. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html  I have this in my notes from rodsbooks site: To move backup to end of drive
 launch gdisk, then type x, then type e, then type w to save your changes, q to quit without changes if not correct.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Who says a GPT which does not take the whole disk is considered corrupt? If you can provide a reference that would help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example using `gdisk`:

```
# gdisk /dev/yourdisk
Command (? for help): v

Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside
at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e'
option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition
table's locations.

Identified 1 problems!
```

`gdisk` can be a bit cryptic to use but here it tells you directly what to do to solve this problem through the experts menu (`x`, `e`).

```
Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): ?
e   relocate backup data structures to the end of the disk

Expert command (? for help): e
Relocating backup data structures to the end of the disk
```

At this point you can adjust partitions or just write it out as is:

```
Expert command (? for help): v

No problems found. 15624933 free sectors (7.5 GiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 15624933 (7.5 GiB) in size.

Expert command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/yourdisk.
```

`parted` can also be used, it will ask you to fix it when you use any command:

```
# parted /dev/yourdisk print
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/yourdisk appears to be used, 
you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 13671875 blocks)
or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore?
```

`fdisk` will resize GPT by writing.

```
# fdisk /dev/yourdisk

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.39.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

GPT PMBR size mismatch (1953124 != 15624999) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device. This problem will be corrected by write.

Command (m for help): w

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
```

Comment: gparted also works

Answer (score 3):

In `gdisk` just `w`rite the partition table. You will see:

```
Warning! Secondary header is placed too early on the disk! Do you want to
correct this problem? (Y/N):
```

Say `y`es. Confirm again if necessary. Done.

---

Alternatively use `fdisk`. You will see:

```
GPT PMBR size mismatch (…) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device. This problem will be corrected by write.
```

Similarly just `w`rite the partition table. Done.